# QEMU virtio-scsi: Cannot see the number of queues after booting VM with virtio-scsi command

Tags: kvm, qemu, scsi, virtio

QEMU newbie here. I am trying to boot a VM using QEMU, for increased performance I am trying to use a virtio-scsi mounted drive. I am following the steps given [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/how-to-emulate-block-devices-with-qemu). However when I boot my VM and I try to check for the virtio-scsi queues using `ls /sys/block/sdb/mq/` I do not see the option of mq, does that mean I was unable to mount a `virtio-scsi` drive? But when I checked my boot up logs I could see I was able to mount my drive.

This is the command I am using to boot my VM

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda x86.img -m 8096 -serial mon:stdio -nographic -smp 4
 --enable-kvm -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi0,num_queues=4 
 -device scsi-hd,drive=drive0,bus=scsi0.0,channel=0,scsi-id=0,lun=0 -drive file=test.img,if=none,id=drive0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopes this helps anyone facing the same issue, there is a config which has to be enabled while compiling the guest kernel -

```
CONFIG_SCSI_MQ_DEFAULT=y
```

You can then use `ls /sys/block/sdq/mq/` to see the number of multi queues.